# Rails before_destory only works with destroy and not with delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, before-filter

I am building a rails applications, where in a part of it, I save to the database, payments information. I need to make these payments un-deleteable.

I have created a `before_destroy` function that kinda works.. but I am having an issue:

here is my code:

```
class StripePayment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :stripe_card

before_destroy :fail

private
def fail
    return false
end
end
```

When I create a payment and try out my code when delete:

`StripePayment.first.destroy` returns false and rollback... Which is exactly what I want.

However, 
`StripePayment.first.delete` passes and deletes the object.

I know the deference between delete and destroy. however, I want to be able to prevent this object from being deleted on the DB (on both `delete()` and `destroy()` calls.

I tried `before_delete` and rails gave me back this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `before_delete' for #<Class:0x007fc1abc37c50>
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
from /Users/alybadawy/developing/repos/finish/finish/app/models/stripe_payment.rb:7:in `<class:StripePayment>'
from /Users/alybadawy/developing/repos/finish/finish/app/models/stripe_payment.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load'
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `block in load_file'
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `load_file'
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:323:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
from (irb):1
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/alybadawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is, to define your own delete method

```
class StripePayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stripe_card

  before_destroy :fail

  def delete
    false
  end

  private
  def fail
      return false
  end
end
```

If you have conditions, where you want to allow deleteion, you can check for it iy your delete method and call `super`

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know that `delete` is one of the methods that I could overwrite. this did the trick. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

that's because delete is one of the functions that skips callbacks in rails

check this out for more info on the subject http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks